# How to intercept `rollback` in gorm?

Tags: go-gorm

I need to execute some things after all create executions fail.

It seems that `callbacks` can be satisfied, but there is a case that if it is an operation in a transaction, it may not actually be executed. I need to do it after `rollback` Treat accordingly. So the question is, how do I intercept `rollback`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use manual transaction in a function like this.

```
func CreateAnimals(db *gorm.DB) error {
  // Note the use of tx as the database handle once you are within a transaction
  tx := db.Begin()
  defer func() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
      tx.Rollback()
    }
  }()

  if err := tx.Error; err != nil {
    return err
  }

  if err := tx.Create(&Animal{Name: "Giraffe"}).Error; err != nil {
     tx.Rollback()
     return err
  }

  if err := tx.Create(&Animal{Name: "Lion"}).Error; err != nil {
     tx.Rollback()
     return err
  }

  return tx.Commit().Error
}
```

If `CreateAnimals` fails then you can do your desired job.

Comment: Thank you, but this method can only be used for specific business logic. I need to rewrite all the business. What I think is how to capture the failure of the transaction globally and then deal with it centrally.

Comment: Afaik, there is no such hook for this.